# "Destroy" controller action appears to be looping through more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have model "Comment", which `belongs_to` another model "User", which in turn `has_many` Comments. On my 'users/edit' page, I have a link to destroy comments:

**users/edit.html.erb**

```
<% @user.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <%= link_to "destroy", destroy_comment_path(comment.id) %>
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller**

```
def destroy
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @user = @comment.user
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
end
```

But I'm getting a bizarre error. The action appears to be looping through more than once. I'm getting this error message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CommentsController
Couldn't find Comment with id=[ID OF THE COMMENT]
```

with this line being highlighted:

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
```

The comment definitely exists before I call the method, and it no longer exists after I call it. If I remove the line `@comment.destroy` then the action runs as expected, and the comment isn't destroyed. So the action must be looping through again, after that line. But I can't imagine why it would be doing that. Does anyone see what might be going wrong? I definitely don't have any other actions called "destroy".

Comment: paste the log file please. and why do you not use a debugger, like pry. or possibly you might have turbo links enabled. who knows.

Comment: Does it work if you use `user_id = @comment.user_id` and `redirect_to edit_user_path(user_id)` instead of `redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)`?

Comment: @AbM Just tried that, it results in the exact same error.

Comment: @argentum47 What do you mean by log file? I tried binding.pry and it didn't really tell me anything. And I disabled turbolinks.

Comment: umm, try ike this. before you hit a destroy, in ine terminal do tail -f log/development.log and then after your reques compeletes with errors, you can take the whole thing and make a gist or use pastie and place the link here or just paster relevant portions in ur question

Comment: when you use binding.pry does it stop twice? if you put in just fter def destroy ? only then you can be sure that its called twice

Comment: You can also copy your web server console output. That will show you exactly what the steps the web server is walking through before the error.

Comment: Also with nested routes I'm not sure you'd need a lot of what you are doing , like `@user = @comment.user`. You are in your user/edit path when you send the command, `user_id` should be a param being passed. Maybe use that instead of referencing something being destroyed i.e. @user, which you are deriving from something you just destroyed.